# Fatal Magento error fix generated after restore

Tags: php, mysql, magento, pdo

My web host restored my magento installation after crash and since then I get error:

> Fatal error: Class Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::insertIgnore, Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::changeTableAutoIncrement) in /lib/Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 35

How do I fix it?

Comment: can you add the contents of *lib/Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php* to your question plz ?

Comment: try to upload code again if you have backup.

Comment: I got it resolved by updating files with new version ... thanks anyway